# Is there a rigorous definition of a law of physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, terminology, definition, laws-of-physics

Is there, in some physics or mathematics text, a rigorous definition of what a law of physics is? I have read many physics books and papers, and while they all talk about particular laws of physics (like light's speed in a vacuum being constant), they don't actually define what a law of physics is. I know that philosophers have tried to define laws of physics, but I am looking for a physics text or a mathematical physics text that tries to rigorously define what a law of physics is.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. We use "law" in  pragmatic ways, not as part of rigorous logic.

Comment: As my high school physics teacher liked to say: "The difference between a law and a theory is arrogance."

Comment: We only give concepts rigorous definitions to prove theorems or classify examples. Even the latter's not too strong of a motivation when it comes to physical laws. It amounts to asking which theorems in unfalsified physical theories you're going to call laws.

Comment: @J.G. Ohm's Law isn't a theorem.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "opinion based" because surely any answer would simply be an opinion.  There's no definitive answer and I cannot imagine how you'd define one.  I do like the comment by @Andrew as it seems both humorous and factual.

Comment: @JohnDoty In a context where that "law" applies, we have the right simplifying assumptions to prove it. Of course, "theorem" is very context-dependent in physics.

Comment: @J.G. Newton's Laws, Ohm's Law, Boyle's Law, Hooke's Law... None of these were proven mathematically. The assumptions behind the theory were constructed to accommodate them.

Comment: @JohnDoty That kind of historical reverse engineering is to be expected. It happened many times even in mathematics, never mind a field whose final arbiter is empirical evidence.

Comment: @J.G. That's not an excuse for erasing the history and claiming the product as "fundamental".

Comment: @JohnDoty I didn't use that word (I don't think anyone did); but whichever plural noun should replace _theorems_ in my first comment's final sentence to make it unobjectionable, my intended key point was laws would be a subset thereof that is not really specified by a rigorous definition, whatever the OP's original aspirations. But if you wish to emphasize the historical fact that "laws" are often enshrined as such before we identify a sense in which they're theorems, fair enough.

Comment: @J.G. Laws are useful summaries of observations of phenomena. Theorems are useful distillations of laws. But the phenomena are fundamental. Failing to understand this leads to things like the result of Sadler's infamous social experiment.

Comment: @JohnDoty Never heard of that experiment, sorry. The most concise compatible merging of our respective points may be "no rigorous definition decides which [useful summaries of observations of phenomena that some theorem may eventually usefully distil] count as laws, either before or after such distillation", or something like that. The words in the square brackets might be so hard to get _exactly_ right it's more trouble than it's worth, but the no-rigorous-definition part is what's vital.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141840/discussion-between-john-doty-and-j-g).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me the word "Law" is typically used of individual equations or relationships, such as Newton's 2nd Law $F=ma$, Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$ (or collectively Newton's Laws of Motion), the First Law of Thermodynamics, etc. In contrast "theory" often refers to a comprehensive set of assumptions and postulates that contain many physical relationships, such as Newton's Theory of Gravitation, the Theory of General Relativity, Quantum Field Theory. All of these essentially rely on a model or picture of how light and matter or space and time behave and what they are composed of, and their predictions (which may include statements of Laws) are based upon these models of the underlying realities being true.

For example, Quantum Mechanical Theory predicts the relationship known as Wien's Displacement Law, which states that the temperature $T$ of a hot body is inversely proportional to the peak wavelength $\lambda$ of the light spectrum that it emits, or in other words $\lambda T = \mathrm{Constant}$.  This law is predicted by the framework of Quantum Theory, but the law was obverved to hold true from experimental data before QT was developed.  And if QT is superseded in the future by a different picture of reality, that new theory will have to agree with Wien's Law.

Thus I would summarize by saying a Law is typically a targeted statement about a certain phenomenon or physical relationship that can often be expressed in a single equation, and is almost always supported by observational data. It does not necessarily claim to explain why that physical relationship is true. A Theory is a comprehensive set of assumptions and postulates designed to explain the "why" and to make a broad variety of predictions.  Because of its broader scope and predictions that apply to essentially every physical situation, it cannot usually be rigorously called "true," because there may always be some unique observation down the line that disagrees with its predictions.  But to answer your main question, much of this is a matter of historical convention, and I don't think there are rigorous definitions of the terms – certainly not ones that all scientists would agree upon.

Comment: This is _exactly_ right. Whenever we use the word "law" we speak in the context of some mathematical relationship. e.g., as you stated, Newton's second law, Newton's law of universal gravitation, the second law of thermodynamics etc. It is because there is a mathematical relationship between quantities that makes perfect predictions (under normal circumstances) that leads us to the notion of a physical _law._ The word "law" implies "rigidity", and mathematical rules are rigid. So a physical theory expressed by a mathematical rule must be a physical law.

Answer (score 1):

A scientific law is a prediction, statement, equation, etc. that is consistent with known observations (possibly within some restricted scope of validity). It falls short of a scientific theory, which does the same but also explains "*why*" the prediction/equation works from some notion of first principles. Newtonian gravity is a law ($F \propto r^{-2}$), while General Relativity is a theory ("space tells matter how to fall, matter tells space how to bend"). Physics is a science, so physical laws meet the same criteria as scientific laws.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a law of physics is a mathematical relationship developed to explain observed phenomena, that over the course of time has been found to accurately describe said phenomena.  Examples are: Newton's second law, Euler's equations for motion of a rigid body, Einstein's equivalence of mass and energy, etc.

Comment: What about laws, like Ohm's Law, that often work, but don't always work?

Comment: It works for a certain set of circumstances; it is not a universal law for all of electromagnetism. Newtons third law also does not work for all electromagnetic interactions or for relativistic situations, but we use it for classical mechanics situations where it applies (two interacting bodies).